Changing URI via Cloudfront to serve different S3 bucket under same distribution?
Any help is greatly appreciated! I am not an AWS expert and I'm trying my best to get this to work by reading docs and articles. I'm also open to other methods of achieving my goal if necessary.
Goal: serve an app from Bucket A if user is logged in (checking for cookie) or serve Bucket B if user is not logged in (static landing page).
I have Bucket A (main app) served as the Default * and Bucket B (landing page) served under the behavior home/*. Here is the Cloudfront function running:
function handler(event) {
      var request = event.request;
      var uri = request.uri;
      var cookies = request.cookies;

      if(!cookies.userToken){
          // change URI when requesting "/" for unauthenticated users
          if(request.uri === '/'){
              var currentUri = request.uri;
              request.uri = currentUri.replace('/', '/home/index.html');
          }
          // currently not changing any other file requests (.ico, .css, etc)
      }

      console.log(JSON.stringify(event.request)) <--Watching Cloudfront Logs
      return request;
}


If I go directly to the /home/index.html URL it will successfully load my static landing page. But I would like to change the URI behind the scenes and just serve the correct bucket based on a cookie in the request. Weirdly enough, last night I did get this to work correctly. But this morning, I rechecked and it isn't loading properly.
Checking Cloudwatch logs, I can see that the URI is being changed to /home/index.html via the Cloudfront function. But it isn't changing the bucket being served. I've disabled caching for testing purposes too.
Extra Advice: I currently have to serve the landing page from s3/home/index.html which is causing Astro problems trying to find the CSS file in my root directory. Ideally I'd serve it from s3/index.html where it would know where the CSS is automatically. Yesterday, I did manage to get that to work--but this morning it isn't pulling up the styles.
Any tips on how to achieve my goal? I've read lots of documentation and looked at a lot of articles. But I don't see a lot on specifically changing the URI to achieve what I'm doing.

Are you wanting to change the URI path of the request within the same S3 bucket (rewrite)? Or choose a completely different S3 bucket (dynamic origin selection)? The question describes a different S3 bucket, but the code is changing the URI path.
